# OGR2OGR with MS SQL on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sql-server, gis, ubuntu-16.04, gdal, ogr2ogr

I need to access a Microsoft SQL Server with OGR2OGR from an Ubuntu Server 16.04. It is working on Microsoft, so the basic setup is fine.

My problem is that when I run my OGR2OGR command (after installing GDAL with sudo apt-get install gdal-bin):

```
ogr2ogr -overwrite -f MSSQLSpatial "MSSQL:server=tcp:<DATABASE_SERVER>,<PORT>;database=<DATABASE_NAME>;uid=<USER>;Pwd=<PASSWORD>;" "<IMPORT PATH FILE>" -nln "<TABLE NAME>" -progress
```

I get the error:

> ERROR 1: Unable to initialize connection to the server for MSSQL:"DATABASE_SERVER";
>   [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found
>   Try specifying the driver in the connection string from the list of available drivers:

I tried to install Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server based on [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568454(v=sql.110).aspx) instruction, but it cannot be installed when gdal is installed. The error is:

> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
>   or been moved out of Incoming.
>   The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    msodbcsql : Depends: unixodbc-utf16 (>= 2.3.1-1) but it is not going to be installed
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I managed to install the Microsoft ODBC driver after a while but it meant removing GDAL. So I can either have GDAL or the Microsoft ODBC driver. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Thanks for your help!

**UPDATE (2017.01.03):** I found the following solution and I also commented on the according article on the MSDN Blog (so far without reply) [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlnativeclient/2016/10/20/odbc-driver-13-0-for-linux-released/comment-page-1/#comment-6905)

Install UnixODBC if not already there

```
sudo apt-get install unixodbc unixodbc-dev
```

Download from somewhere: msodbcsql-11.0.2270.0.tar.gz  (it could be better to use msodbcsql-13.x.x.x.tar.gz but I was not able to find it) and

```
tar xvfz msodbcsql-11.0.2270.0.tar.gz
cd msodbcsql-11.0.2270.0
ldd lib64/libmsodbcsql-11.0.so.2270.0
```

If there are missing dependencies install them, in my case it could be done like this: (everything except the apt-get install is to fix the naming of the file by creating a link:)

```
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0 libssl-dev
cd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo ln -s libssl.so.1.0.0 libssl.so.10
sudo ln -s libcrypto.so.1.0.0 libcrypto.so.10
```

Installing and cleaning up:

```
sudo bash ./install.sh install --force --accept-license

rm -rf /tmp/msodbcubuntu
```

If the Driver is not found by the tool using it, (e.g. ogr2ogr or pyodbc) edit /etc/odbcinst.ini and create a connector for [SQL Server]

```
[SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-11.0.so.2270.0
Threading=1
UsageCount=2
```

Answer (score 1):

Shamelessly from : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

```
sudo su 
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17
```

Verify with

```
ogr2ogr --formats
```

Which should then list:

```
MSSQLSpatial -vector- (rw+): Microsoft SQL Server Spatial Database
```